# Why get_posts from a category id doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

use the following code to get portfolio type posts from category id, but it doesn't work.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => $items, 'post_type'=>'portfolio','orderby' => 'post_date','order'=>'DESC','category' => 5 );
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($posts as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    $return_html='......';
}
```

however,if I leave the category id empty, it' fine and will show all categories posts. I'm sure that there are many posts under category 5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that "category" a custom taxonomy category on a custom post type "portfolio"? If so, then category won't get it; you'll need to use a [taxonomy query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Answer (score 0):

```
/* below mention code u may have the idea */ 
/* You have to not pass the category id in the argument. */
/* You have to pass category type and category slug*/
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10,'orderby' => 'post_date','order'=>'DESC','category-type' => $category-slug );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );              
if($loop->have_posts()) :
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
/*... Your post data here */

endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thanks I sloved. Must use 'tax_query' in get_posts.